# Is there a wireless thermostat that will make relocating easier?

Tags: hvac, thermostat

I've got a single zone which covers all three upstairs bedrooms in my home and the thermostat is located in the master bedroom.  We prefer it to be somewhat cooler at night, but the baby in the nursery would be better off with a warmer room. (We have a hydronic system with baseboard radiators, just heat no cooling.)

Moving it is doable since I have attic access, but it seems like an easier solution would be to use some kind of wireless system - the temperature sensor would go in the nursery while the "brains" would connect in the master bedroom in place of the existing thermostat.

I searched for such an animal on Amazon and didn't really come up with anything at a reasonable price.  Can anyone suggest a product that they've used?  If it's more than $100 I'll probably just physically relocate it... but it really seems like something like this should exist!

Comment: Wireless thermostats range from ~$100.00 and up. I doubt you'll find one cheaper, and if you do it will likely be crap anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I'm really happy with my Honeywell wireless thermostat. Battery lasts a very long time and it works through 4 floors. A quick Google search shows several options below $100... Something like [this for $65](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001GLUM9Q) perhaps? Not the one I have though and not sure if it includes the receiver.

Comment: Thanks, that actually got me heading in the right direction although it's not quite what I need.  It appears that those units are intended to be used as components of an entire "FocusPRO Ecosystem" (for lack of a better description).  I don't think it'd work properly without the master unit.

I found some other solutions and am currently bidding on a base + remote unit from a company called Venstar... seems like a workable solution.

Comment: FocusPro thermostat can be installed with EIM module which interfaces with equipment like regular thermostat. So you only need thermostat and EIM but no other ecosystem.